# Create answer from comment when there are no answers

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, answers-as-comments

Recently I've seen a couple of questions (across various SE sites) that I could answer, upon reading the question & comments I've found that it's been answered as a comment but there's no actual answer.

Is it ok for me to provide an answer that mostly consists of some-one else's comment?
(I'd try to improve on the comment by expanding on it or providing examples, give attribution to the original commenter & wait a few days before doing so.)

I dislike the idea of "stealing" someone else's rep, but I also feel every good question should have an answer (ideally accepted), since this improves the question for future users.

Are there any rules/recommended practices for doing this, or should I even be doing this?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. If you can make it a good answer (Comments rarely are good answers) then by all means do so. They could have done it themselves, so you're not stealing anything. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143514/comments-have-become-answers/143517#143517

Comment: @Bart, your answer to this question most likely is one of these mentioned by the OP. It answers the question, but actually is a comment ;)

Comment: @Spontifixus Feel free to make it an answer and steal my rep.

Comment: @Bart done. am I now oficially a reputation thief? ;)

Comment: @Spontifixus For shame good Sir, for shame. I might just flag your answer for moderator attention. Turning lousy comments into good answers. I hope you're happy with yourself. *shakes head*

Comment: @Bart on second thought - You're right. This question has been answered too many a times.

Comment: When I write a partial answer in a comment, it usually means that I'm too lazy to formulate a complete answer. Feel free to base your answer on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, go ahead. If you can make it a good answer (Comments rarely are good answers) then by all means do so. They could have done it themselves, so you're not stealing anything. Related: [Comments have become answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143514/comments-have-become-answers/143517#143517)